# How to build/extend a designer for Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, gui-designer, vs-extensibility

I just finished a quick intro in Linq2Sql and I decided to try my hands at it. 
To my dismay, it appears the dbml designer supports SqlServer and SqlClient providers only.

After reading around, I found that I had to hand-code my classes in order to do Linq2Sql for other data providers like SQLite (which I use very often).

I wanted to know:

- Are there any resources from which I can learn how to extend the dbml designer in Visual Studio?
- If there is no way to extend the dbml designer, how do I build custom code generation designers for visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build or extend the designer. All you need is a valid DBML file.

I recommend to check [DbLinq](http://dblinq.codeplex.com/) and it's source code:

> [DbLinq] allows for Linq as well as DBML file
>   generation using non-MS databases,
>   such as MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle,
>   Ingres, SQLite, FireBird, and SQL
>   Server

BTW, are you targeting a particular DB server? (DbLinq is not probably the best choice in your case as it seems to be unmaintained since some time, and there are more and more vendor-provided LinqToSql/Entities providers...)